# Android-equivalent to iOS's ASWebAuthenticationSession

Tags: android, ios, authentication, oauth, single-sign-on

Trying to implement Azure sign-in, and I used `SFAuthenticationSession` and `ASWebAuthentication` in iOS, but I don't know what the equivalent is for Android. Is there an API that provides the same functionality?

Comment: Have you find SFAuthenticationSession equivalent API in Android ?

Comment: Upon looking at other implementations I decided that a WebView with custom logic on loading each page should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The [AppAuth library](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) is the component that will offer something closer to what you are looking for.

Another [alternative](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) is to use a native authentication but that requires your backend server to validate tokens with google.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into the https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/browser/trusted/package-summary and https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/browser

This is how auth0 sdk is doing https://github.com/auth0/Auth0.Android

So, I looked into this topic, you can use the chrome custom tab, and open the url of the login site, however, your url should call a url once the auth is successful and that would trigger a android deep link. Your app/activity should register the intent-filter like the following:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="demo" />
</intent-filter>
```

If the auth is successful and the browser calls the redirected url something like "demo://.....", your activity would get a new intent.

See this for better explanation. https://joebirch.co/android/oauth-on-android-with-custom-tabs/